# Magento 2 Error on setting deployment mode to production

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I enabled vendor's list of modules & setup upgrade them. I changed deploying mode from developer to production. During that i encounter an error

```
sagar@sg2 public_html]$ php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production
Enabled maintenance mode
Starting compilation
Something went wrong while compiling generated code. See the error log for details.
Command returned non-zero exit code:
```

`/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/usr/bin/php -f /home/ghema/public_html/bin/magento setup:di:compile`

Comment: Did you check the error log ? What's in there ?

Comment: On exception log : there was on error on template i had overriden to my theme. I commented it. On system.log there is an error saying Compilation was started.
%message% 0/7 [>---------------------------]   0% 1 sec 72.0 MiB%message% 0/7 [>---------------------------]   0% 1 sec 72.0 MiBProxies code generation... 0/7 [>---------------------------]   0% 1 sec 72.0 MiB
Proxies code generation... 1/7 [====>-----------------------]  14% 1 sec 77.5 MiB
Repositories code generation... 1/7 [====>-----------------------]  14% 1 sec 77.5 MiB [] []

Answer (score 2):

Since error is occurring during code generation it's likely to be an issue with either your custom theme or any addon modules/plugins.

If you run command `php bin/magento setup:di:compile` on it's own,code generation should break at the point of error and should throw a [ReflectionException] (or another error) that should point you in the right direction.